# Exponentiation category theory

Tags: category-theory

Let be $$curry(eval_{AB})=id_{B^{A}}, $$ $B^{A}$  is an exponential object, $curry(g)(c)=g_{c}$ and $eval(f,a)=f(a)$, but how to prove it?
Let $C$ be a category with all binary products and let $A$ and $B$ be objects of $C$.
eval is a special evaluation function.

Comment: Could you detail a little more your notations, this is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $eval : B^A \times A \to B$ is the counit of the adjunction $- \times A \dashv (-)^A$, so that it corresponds via exponential transpose to $id_{B^A}$ by definition.

In more detail, $curry$ is the natural bijection

$$\mathrm{Hom}(C \times A, B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(C, B^A)$$

If we pick $C = B^A$ and on the right side we take $id_{B^A} \in \mathrm{Hom}(B^A,B^A)$, $eval$ is the unique morphism such that $curry(eval) = id_{B^A}$. This is a general fact about adjunctions: units and counits are adjuncts to the appropriate identity morphisms.

Also note that some expressions as $f(a)$ don't make much sense if you're thinking of an arbitrary cartesian closed category where morphisms aren't functions.